# Can a Reactjs `Context` have multiple providers?

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I wonder if I can have multiple `<Context.Provider/>` to provide the value for a `Context`. I'd like to have multiple components (the contents of various pages) provide values such as the page title to a topbar.
Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but each consumer will only get the value from a single provider (the nearest provider up the component tree).

Comment: Why can't you store it in the single context?

Comment: @NicholasTower Thanks, so in my case it would work? I mean, I have only one consumer, my topbar

Comment: @JoelHager well I should have multiple providers for that to work, right? Could you please give me an example on what you mean? I'm not sure I'm understanding it right

Comment: @JavierG it doesn't sound like it will work. It sounds like you want your topbar to get data from *multiple* sources. It can only read from one.

Comment: @NicholasTower thanks, so I could simply have a global variable atrached to the window object and read and write values there? I don't want to use fancy frameworks like Redux for this

Comment: Does something like this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68640880/8690857 Or are you really just asking if you can use more than one React context (i.e. different contexts)?

Comment: You just store multiple values or functions / reducers in your single store.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks but no, I don't think that would answer my question

Comment: Right, so it wasn't clear if you want to use multiples of the same context provider, or if you are wanting to use several *different* providers. Though I'm rereading your post again now and sounds like you want to use several of the same provider, in several places providing to *different* ReactSubTrees. A [mcve] for what you are trying to do would probably be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

You can make multiple but it will affect one context so if you need multiple functionalities you can implement them in one context and use them by destructuring

`<DemoContext.Provider value={{function1, function2 function3}}></DemoContext.Provider>`

use

```
const {function1}= useContext(DemoContext)
```

Comment: Thanks, it would come handy to pass the topbar some more stuff